# Regex for only two comma separated values, keeping second value optional

Tags: java, regex

I am creating regex for two comma separated values (example - coordinates), i am using regex like below -

```
^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$
```

The above regex  mandates two comma separated values, but i want the second value as optional including comma, so i tried changing the regex like this -

```
^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)(,\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$)?
```

This is working but and keeping the second value optional, but it is also allowing comma without any second value like below -

> 3456,

What can be added in the regex to not allowing comma if second value is not present ? Thanks.

Comment: `$` anchor must not be part of the optional group, but placed behind it.

Comment: @SebastianProske Thank You, this seems to work, this is my regex now =  ^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)(,\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?))?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misplaced the quantifier with the  anchor.

Use

```
^(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)(,\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?))?$
                                     ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eAScnV/1).

You may adjust the number of capturing groups in your pattern and convert the optional group into non-capturing by adding `?:`after the opening `(`. I'd use it like

```
^(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:,\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/eAScnV/2).

Also note you do not need to escape a hyphen outside a character class.

When using it in Java, do not forget to use double backslashes to define a literal backslash in the string literal and omit `^` and `$` if you use the pattern with `.matches()` method:

```
s.matches("-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:,\\s*-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?")
```

Details:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)` - Group 1 matching an optional hyphen, 1+ digits, then an optional sequence (Group 2) of a dot followed with one or more digits
- `(,\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?))?` - an optional sequence (Group 3) matching one or zero occurrences of:

  - `,` - comma
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)` - Group 4 matching

    - `-?` - an optional hyphen
    - `\d+` - one or more digits
    - `(\.\d+)?` - Group 5 matching an optional sequence of a dot followed with  1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Sorry, mobile access is horrible. I can't format the explanation correctly.

Comment: better? You missed a space after the first minus of your list.